# Text over video background goes opaque

Tags: css, html

I'm using a video background with a text header in the middle. When I don't have the video coded in the text is white but as soon as I add the video the white text goes opaque, I don't want this. The HTML;

```
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="container">
    <video autoplay muted>    
        <source src="videoone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text wow fadeInDown">
          <h1>Made to Represent</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried using `!important`in the CSS on the related settings.
I've put together a simplified version on codepen here - https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/xyQzNj

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `z-index: 1` from the `.top-content video` CSS section would be the best way to fix the problem. As follows;

```
.top-content video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding position: absolute and add z-index: 999 to your class

```
.top-content .text h1 {
    letter-spacing: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to set that `z-index`, if you remove `z-index: 1` from the `.top-content video` rule it's a better solution imho. But your idea works.